# Creating a popup dialog when an error occurs Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want a dialog box to appear when an error occurs however I dont know how to do it. Where I would like the code to appear can be seen in the code below. So when this function is called a popup dialog box appears.

`.fail(function(){ 
            alert("$.get failed!"); //replace with failed dialog 
        })
    });`

Answer (score 8):

So I'm guessing this is what you are talking about.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Have this embedded in your html somewhere.

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupCloseLeft" class="ui-content" style="max-width:280px">
 <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Close</a>
 <p>I have a close button at the top left corner with simple HTML markup.</p>
 </div>
```

And then in your fail function just call this.

```
$( "#popupCloseLeft" ).popup("open");
```

Comment: This gives "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'".

Comment: @PatrickBassut interesting. Do you have an example of this happening?